# Netlogo: How to create links to turtle's two immediate neighbours?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I want to ask all turtles to link with their two immediate neighbors.

Below is my code, but all of them are wrong.

`ask turtles [ create-links-with  n-of 2 other turtles] ;; should link with 2 immediate neighbours rather than 2 random turtles`

`ask turtles [ create-links-with  n-of 2 neighbors] ;; Run mistake: CREATE-LINKS-WITH expected input to be a turtle agentset but got the agentset (agentset, 2 patches) instead.`

`ask turtles [ create-links-with min-n-of 2 turtles [distance myself] ] ;; Run mistake: A turtle cannot link to itself. Error while turtle 10 running CREATE-LINKS-WITH`

Any one any idea how to fix my code? Thank you very much!

Comment: The last one seems to be the most promising to me. The error there is, that in the turtle-set, that `min-n-of` returns, contains the turtle, that would create the links (since the distance to myself is 0).
Try `ask turtles [ create-links-with min-n-of other turtles [distance myself] ].`
The `other` omits the `myself` turtle

Comment: The comment by @Lena is right apart from a typo (i.e. `ask turtles [create-links-with min-n-of 2 other turtles [distance myself]]`).
However you might still have a problem: if you're asking this as per the other question you posted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67750495/netlogo-how-to-create-a-circle-without-specific-radius, hoping you managed to create a random-size circle), you might not get the desired result if your world wraps vertically/horizontally and your circle is large enough. In that case, the closest turtle to a turtle might not be the one sitting next to it in the circle.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `[create-links-with min-n-of 2 turtles...]`, the `min-n-of 2 turtles` part makes the turtle executing the command count itself as one of the 2 target turtles. So the error

> A turtle cannot link to itself. Error while turtle 10 running
> CREATE-LINKS-WITH

occurs since you want to create links with immediate 2 turtles.

Try:

`min-n-of 2 other turtles`

Here, `other` gives all the turtles except the turtle executing the command.

Overall: `create-links-with min-n-of 2 other turtles [distance myself]`